# ¡HolaMundo! no se imprime bien en pantalla

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas con el programa `¡Hola Mundo!` y no estoy encontrando el error. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public class HolaMundo { // Clase principal                                                              
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.print("¡Hola mundo!"); 
    }
}
```

Cuando lo compilo utilizando el `javac HolaMundo.java`, no me genera ningún error. El tema es que cuando ejecuto el programa utilizando el `java HolaMundo`, en la pantalla de la terminal, en vez de aparecer `¡Hola mundo!`, me aparece `Â¡Hola mundo!`. Haga lo que haga, siempre me aparece esa `Â` que no debería estar ahí.

Por si tiene algo que ver, el *path* que tengo es el siguiente:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;

¿Me podrán ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: Es un problema de encodaje de la consola o de la Java Virtual Machine, o del IDE. Según donde esté el problema la solución puede ser diferente. Por código, puedes setearlo a UTF-8 haciendo esto: `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println("¡Hola mundo!");`

Comment: Ese codigo que me pasaste, lo coloco dentro del codigo del programa? O lo escribo directamente en la consola? Lo que me di cuenta es que al parecer es un problema de interpretacion de la consola ya que el programa que uso (Geany) esta configurado en UTF-8 pero todo lo que son caracteres como ¡¿$%&#° etc no me los imprime en la consola como tal sino que me devuelve cualquier cosa.

Comment: En el programa. Puedes sustituir ambas líneas por esta: `System.out.print("¡Hola mundo!");`

Comment: Si corres el jar desde la consola, entonces puedes escribirlo así: `java -Dfile.encoding=utf8  -jar  tuarchivo.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Guarda el archivo de manera que sea del tipo UTF-8 y no ANSI.
Por ejemplo si usas bloc de notas, tienes que cambiar el formto en vez de ANSI a UTF-8, Si usas sublime text, en File->Save with Econding->UTF-8, por que aveces el IDE no lo guarda como debería, me ha pasado y he tenido que borrar, después crear un archivo nuevo con el mismo código pero guardarlo de esta forma.

Comment: Eso sería un buen comentario, si preguntarías por el IDE que el OP esta usando. Luego podrías responder, explicando como se configura el formato en que se guardan los archivos.

Comment: Como puedo ver eso?

Comment: el IDE es el entorno donde desarrollas por ejemplo: Visual Studio, NetBeans, etc. @MartinP